# Does overriding a function instantiate the base function? (getting error)

Tags: c++, templates, overriding

I would like to write a converter. I would prefer a base class that already handles the trivial cases where **InputType** can be directly converter to **OutputType**, say float to double.

However, in this shortened example, I get an error:

> error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'const Eigen::Vector2d' to 'std::tuple<double,double>'

To me that looks like, the base class and **set** function are instantiated, despite the function being overridden. Since there is no conversion between Eigen::Vector2d and std::tuple the error appears.
Am I missing something? What would be a proper way to achieve the initial goal?

The base class which is supposed to also handle trivial cases like OutputType = InputType:

```
template <typename InputType, typename OutputType>
class DefaultConverter 
{
public:
    virtual void set(const InputType& input)
    {
        output = static_cast<OutputType>(input);
    }
protected:
    OutputType output;
};
```

Now the derived class that causes the error:

```
class Array2Eigen : public DefaultConverter<Eigen::Vector2d, std::tuple<double, double>>
{
public:
    void set(const Eigen::Vector2d& input) override
    {
        output = std::make_tuple(input[0], input[1]);
    }
    double getFirst() { return std::get<0>(output); }
};
```

Some code for testing:

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Eigen::Vector2d input(1.0, 2.0);
    Array2Eigen converter;
    converter.set(input);

    std::cout << converter.getFirst() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: virtual methods are instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual methods are instantiated in the same time than the class, so it should be correct.

You might provide 2 versions:

```
template <typename InputType, typename OutputType, typename Enabler = void>
class DefaultConverter 
{
public:
    virtual ~DefaultConverter() = default;
    virtual void set(const InputType& input) = 0;

protected:
    OutputType output;
};

template <typename InputType, typename OutputType>
class DefaultConverter<InputType, OutputType,
                       std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<InputType, OutputType>>>
{
public:
    virtual ~DefaultConverter() = default;
    virtual void set(const InputType& input)
    {
        output = static_cast<OutputType>(input);
    }

protected:
    OutputType output;
};
```

Comment: wait, what? But he's **override**ing the base function... how come it's still used??

Comment: `Array2Eigen[}.DefaultConverter<..>::set(input)` should be a legal call

Comment: I get it now. The template `DefaultConverter<Eigen::Vector2d, std::tuple<double, double>>` is instantiated, and that will contain illegal statements.. thanks for the hint, informative question&answer